# optimise my solution

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, process-improvement

I just solve this but want know more efficient way to do matrix multiplication

```
M :
------
1 1 0
0 0 5
3 2 0
```

f[n] = M^n

I have implemented using [Exponentiation_by_squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Is there more efficient then this ?

Comment: The whole modulo thing makes me think there could be some kind of mathematical hackery to turn it into simple equation.

Comment: yes I also think big number multiplication take more time

Comment: Shouldn't the modulo also be in calculateProduction for each variable? The way you have it now seems to be incorrect.

Comment: `First I have thought recursive solution with dynamic programming but it take more time` Hang on... It shouldn't. Post the dynamic programming version.

Comment: sure I will update my post ..

Comment: @UmNyobe I have update my post let see.

Comment: dynamic programming won't help, because each value is only needed once.

Answer (score 4):

Since N can be as large as 10^12 it should have been clear that iterating from 1 to N is not the desired solution.  The key insight is that the recursion can be rewritten as V(i) = M * V(i-1), where

```
 V(i) = [RR(i), MM(i), PP(i)] (a column vector)
```

so

```
 V(0) = [ 3 1 0 ]
```

and

```
 M = | 1 0 3 |
     | 1 0 2 |
     | 0 5 0 |
```

Now V(N) = M^N * V(0)

We can calculate M^N in log(N) time by [repeatedly squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_with_integer_exponents):

```
M^2 = M * M
M^4 = M^2 * M^2
...
```

Perform all calculations mod 100000006 to avoid accumulating large numbers.

To arrive at this solution, it helps to have a basic familiarity with linear algebra.

Comment: `helps to have a` ***basic*** `familiarity with linear algebra`. Not that basic...

Comment: aggree @UmNyobe , `@kevin` can you please explain more in detail .. How you declare M .. on which basis you have take M

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be possible to mod all calculations and arrive at correct solution using this approach.

Comment: `@kevin` and can you help me give exact program (if possible) cause i am newbie in algorithm. So i want to see this how can you implement such matrix and all ..
If possible plz give program.

Comment: Basically he poses the recurrence above as evaluating a system of equations. He translate that to a matrix-vector multiplication (how it is solved) and now get a new recurrence `V(i+1) = M V(i)`. This can be translated as `V(N) = M^N * V(0)`. Now the problem is reduced to computing `M^N (exponentiation)` on a 3x3 matrix. this is algorithmic porn

Comment: @UmNyobe I was taught this in school (albeit a maths-heavy one). It's already avoiding the harder problems like computing M^n as quickly as possible by giving an OK algorithm. The problem is a first order (simplest) [Recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). The solution presented here is at the very beginning of the "Solving" and "Solving using linear algebra". Then it's a matter of computing an exponentiated matrix, and the OP proposes using squaring as an easy shortcut

Comment: @Ordous same here, but it seems I forgot what have been taught. Coming with this by your own is definitely not easy.

Comment: @Euphoric I'm fairly certain you could since `(a mod n) * (b mod n) = (ab mod n)` and `(a mod n) + (b mod n) = (a+b) mod n` and matrix multiplication (and exponentiation) can be decomposed into integer multiplication and summation. As long as your variables are long enough to contain `100000006^2 * 3` and you do mods *in between matrix multiplications* you should be absolutely fine.

Comment: @Euphoric all say (a mod n) * (b mod n) = (ab mod n)

but eg: 
`(13 mod 10) * (15 mod 10) != ((13*15) mod 10)`
`3*5 != 5`

Comment: @Euphoric , @UmN , @kevin
can you please tell me or refer a link to do `exponentiated matrix`. What could best dynamic solution to compute this in JAVA

Comment: @ankit337 Actually, you are missing mod 10 of whole left side. That will make it equal.

Comment: @Euphoric:  I'm 100% sure you can take the modulus after each operation.  It is only necessary to show that if a = b (mod N) then for any c, a + c = b + c (mod N) and a * c = b * c (mod N).

Comment: @UmNyobe: The fundamentals of vector and matrix multiplication is  the most basic topic in linear algebra.

Comment: @ankit337: you can get further help only after presenting evidence of some effort on your part.  Most of us get paid to program.  Why should we work for free?